# Problem Understanding circuit of 5-volt battery charger IC

Tags: battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, charger, powerbanks

[image]

The attached image is from the datasheet of [IP5306 Fully-Integrated Power Bank System](http://www.injoinic.com/wwwroot/uploads/files/20200221/0405f23c247a34d3990ae100c8b20a27.pdf). What is the significance of adding 2 ohms (R3) and 0.5 ohms (R4) resistance in the circuit? It is expected to have a low ESR capacitor in boost converters. But how that extra 2 ohm is adding facility? And the 0.5-ohm resistor, what's the function of that? And how did they selected this value?

Comment: @Justme There are a couple of additional things I'm trying to understand about this schematic: (1) Is there nothing at all connected to the negative terminal of the battery?! Is there simply a lead from the positive terminal, from which everything eventually goes to ground by some path or another? I thought all DC circuits had to actually have, you know, a *circuit* from positive to negative, not just positive to ground. (2) What the heck is going on with the subsystem enclosed in the blue outline? My Engrish isn't good enough to interpret "When the output without partial pressure resistance…"

Comment: @jdmc (1) Assumption is battery negative is connected to ground, since all the voltages are referenced to ground. It's just not drawn in the picture. (2) If you don't need the voltage divider resistors to tell some USB devices how much current they can draw from this USB port, then the whole circuit inside the blue box can be omitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resistor R3:

Adding a damping resistance on USB supply voltage input is standard practice.

And there is at least two reasons why it is there.

Since the cables have inductance, connecting a wire from charger to this powerbank input means the charging cable and the capacitance C1 forms an LC tank which can oscillate at the resonance frequency when the cable is connected (5V step to a LC filter, step response is oscillations at the natural frequency of the system). The oscillations will ring and can go above 5V until the oscillations fade away to 5V DC. It can stress the system and even cause damage if the system can not handle the peak ringing voltages.

So the extra resistor and capacitor is a RC snubber, it helps to suppress the ringing.

The other reason is that USB specifications only allow a certain amount of capacitance directly at the device input, and that's 10uF, more capacitance is not allowed. However, there are also DC input limits, and those combined, the waveform of current (or energy) taken by the device is measured.

So it is possible that as there is already a 10uF capacitor needed in the device, another 10uF capacitor is used for the snubber, and then a suitable resistor is determined by measuring which is most effective suppressing ringing or passing USB specs.

At DC the RC filter does nothing, but beyond the cutoff frequency of about 8 kHz, it's effectively a 2 ohm impedance for high frequency AC ripples.

So the R3 and C6 are not for bypassing the charger chip. At 750 kHz charging frequency, the capacitor C1 that is directly connected to the chip is more than enough to provide low impedance bypass.

Resistor R4:

The datasheet says the BAT pin is for sensing battery voltage. So to avoid errors in the operation due to the switch mode conversion, the battery voltage is RC filtered with R4 and C7 which forms a 14 kHz low-pass RC filter. That leaves enough margin for quick detection of average battery voltage even if it is being charged at 750 kHz or discharged at 500 kHz.

Again, since the only other capacitor value in the board is 22uF it is used here too, and the resistance is selected based on getting suitable RC filter cutoff frequency, and even based on voltage drop due to current into BAT pin if that is used as the supply pin to power up the chip and LEDs etc.

And for this case too, the C7 is not a bypass cap for the switching converter, it's only for bypassing the chip. All the other 22uF capacitors that are directly connected are the switching bypass capacitors.

Comment: Please see my comment under the original question above, thanks.